# How to run Blazor application published to folder as .exe in HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

When I publish my Blazor WebAssembly application to a folder on my machine and run the executable, I am able to access the application at the following address:

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, I need to run the application as HTTPS. How can I do this running the .exe?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Kestrel in your `appsettings.json` file

Simple example

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "cert/MyCert.pfx",
          "Password": "1234567890"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does one determine what should go in the Path and Password fields?